# How can I appendChild to a text field?

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

I am trying to create a text field which takes user input and creates a tag if its a valid email id.

I am using `appendChild()` method to append the tags after creating them but I am unable to do so.

Below is the code to append the `<span>` to the field:

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="customField" class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows="1"></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("customField").appendChild(spanParent);
```

I am not sure that this is the right way to do this, but it would be great if someone can help.

Comment: It depends on what the `customField` element is. Note that you're adding an element to its children. If it's like an `<input>` tag, it doesn't have any children. Maybe you want to use `insertBefore` rather than `appendChild`? Try to elaborate a bit more about what is not working or what is happening or even better provide more code by using a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or something.

Comment: Added the HTML code, also will look at the `insertBefore` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @sonlexqt in the comments we cannot append to `<input>` tag we have to create a `<div>` with `contenteditable=true` and can append any `<div>` to the `<input>` field.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `appendChild()` with the input field, instead, use with the container of that input field, see live action here: https://jsfiddle.net/37b2fa2e/2/.

You should also consider using the [insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) method, which helps inserting the specified node before the reference node as a child of the current node.

Comment: your answer does explains a bit but doesn't answer my question, I want the tag inside the input field not after the field. Thanks.

Comment: The `<input>` tag doesn't have any children. If you insist on adding the tag inside the input field, my suggestion is that you should create a `<div>` element then restyle it to looks like "an input field". You can edit text inside a `<div>` element using the `contenteditable="true"` attribute. See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable